# error: ‘std::chars_format’ has not been declared

Tags: c++

A minimal part of my code is as follows:

```
#include <charconv>
#include <string_view>
#include <cmath>

int main() {

    return 0;
}

double strparse(std::string_view s, int field, int a, int b) {
    double candidates[3];
    auto format = std::chars_format::fixed;
    return 0;
}
```

However, compiling it under the command:

```
g++ -std=c++17 bob.cpp
```

Using g++ 9.2.1

returns:

```
bob.cpp: In function ‘double strparse(std::string_view, int, int, int)’:
bob.cpp:12:24: error: ‘std::chars_format’ has not been declared
   12 |     auto format = std::chars_format::fixed;
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm not sure why this isn't compiling - can someone help?

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/NymdC4)

Comment: what version of g++ do you have?  What is the version of your standard library (libstdc+++)?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AaM8hErI6WSLAM6Z).

Comment: edited my question. using g++ 9.2.1 and libstdc++.so.6

Comment: Looks like GCC and clang only have partial support: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support (search for P0067R5)

Comment: It works on MSVC, newest clang and gcc fails https://godbolt.org/z/NymdC4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it wouldn't compile is because there is [only partial GCC support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) for `std::chars_format::fixed`.